# How to get every possible permutation from a list of numbers and store in a dataframe?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list of numbers, 1-6, that I need every possible permutation of, and need to store in a dataframe. But I also need the dataframe to have the columns named as 'Month 1', 'Month 2', 'Month 3', etc.

So I'd like to have something like this:

```
Month 1  Month 2  Month 3  Month 4  Month 5  Month 6
1        2        3        4        5        6
1        2        3        4        6        5
1        2        3        5        4        6
1        2        3        5        6        4

etc.
```

I need all 720 possible permutations stored.

How do I do this? I've tried using `itertools.permutation` but am having trouble.

Comment: Show what you tried and then we'll help you fix the error. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd
h = ['month-{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,7)]
b = [list(i) for i in permutations([i for i in range(1, 7)])]
pd.DataFrame(b, columns=h)

#output 
Out[12]:
     month-1  month-2  month-3  month-4  month-5  month-6
0          1        2        3        4        5        6
1          1        2        3        4        6        5
2          1        2        3        5        4        6
3          1        2        3        5        6        4
4          1        2        3        6        4        5
5          1        2        3        6        5        4
6          1        2        4        3        5        6
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that don't show their effort.

Comment: @Barmar While I agree with you that santokiya should show more effort by posting what he tried, I do not feel you should be discouraging people who wish to try and give answers.

Comment: @ycx If we don't discourage answers to bad questions, we encourage bad questions. He needs to learn which questions deserve answers.

Comment: @Barmar santokiya is clearly a new user. New users won't learn anything this way imo

Comment: @ycx I was talking about mamun learning what kinds of questions to answer.

Comment: The OP obviously won't learn that we don't provide free coding if people actually do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.permutations` lets you do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

a = itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(a), columns=['Month' + str(i) for i in range(1,7)])
```

Would yield:

```
Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   2   3   4   6   5
2   1   2   3   5   4   6
3   1   2   3   5   6   4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your trouble in getting a dataframe out of the permutations. Here is my example.

```
from itertools import permutations
a= np.arange(6)
df= pd.DataFrame([comb for comb in permutations(a)],
                 columns=['Month 1','Month 2' ,'Month 3','Month 4','Month 5','Month 6'])
```